# How to add new key value pair in request headers for Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

My api calling code is similar like this

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56851/");

//Here I want add Authentication Header as new key value pair 
//Something similar like this 
//client.Headers["AuthenticationToken"]="FASFASFA#$";

        var id = txtSearch.Text.Trim();
        var url = "api/User/" + id;
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var users = response.Content.ReadAsAsync&lt;Users&gt;().Result;

            MessageBox.Show("User Found : " + 
            users.FirstName + " "  + users.LastName);
        }
```

How to add new key value pair in request headers for Web API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.authorization(v=vs.118).aspx) property of `HttpClient`:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
          new AuthenticationHeaderValue("YourAuthenticationScheme", "FASFASFA#$");
```